# Xamarin forms AppIcon.xcassets causing error on upload.

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I'm getting the following errors when uploading my app to TestFlight.

[image: Xcode Errors]

However, I don't see any place for the `missing` icons in the Xamarin assets menu. (76x76, 167x167, and 152x152)

[image: Xamarin Forms Asset.xcassets]

I thought I could work around it by editing the **Contents.json** file in Sublime, but it appears that the 76x76 icon is accounted for in the file... so I don't think it would work. I have everything up-to-date (Visual Studio, Xcode, etc).

```
{
  "images": [
{
  "size": "20x20",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
{
  "filename": "apple-touch-icon-60x60.png",
  "size": "20x20",
  "scale": "3x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
{
  "size": "29x29",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
{
  "size": "29x29",
  "scale": "3x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
{
  "size": "40x40",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
{
  "filename": "apple-touch-icon-120x120.png",
  "size": "40x40",
  "scale": "3x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
{
  "filename": "Divco120.png",
  "size": "60x60",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
{
  "filename": "apple-touch-icon-180x180.png",
  "size": "60x60",
  "scale": "3x",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
{
  "filename": "Divco20.png",
  "size": "20x20",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "filename": "Divco40.png",
  "size": "20x20",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "size": "29x29",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "size": "29x29",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "filename": "Divco40.png",
  "size": "40x40",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "size": "40x40",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "filename": "Divco167.png",
  "size": "83.5x83.5",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "filename": "apple-touch-icon-76x76.png",
  "size": "76x76",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "filename": "apple-touch-icon-152x152.png",
  "size": "76x76",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "ipad"
},
{
  "filename": "Divco1024.png",
  "size": "1024x1024",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "ios-marketing"
},
{
  "size": "60x60",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "car"
},
{
  "size": "60x60",
  "scale": "3x",
  "idiom": "car"
},
{
  "role": "notificationCenter",
  "size": "24x24",
  "subtype": "38mm",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "notificationCenter",
  "size": "27.5x27.5",
  "subtype": "42mm",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "companionSettings",
  "size": "29x29",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "companionSettings",
  "size": "29x29",
  "scale": "3x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "appLauncher",
  "size": "40x40",
  "subtype": "38mm",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "appLauncher",
  "size": "44x44",
  "subtype": "40mm",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "appLauncher",
  "size": "50x50",
  "subtype": "44mm",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "quickLook",
  "size": "86x86",
  "subtype": "38mm",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "quickLook",
  "size": "98x98",
  "subtype": "42mm",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "role": "quickLook",
  "size": "108x108",
  "subtype": "44mm",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "watch"
},
{
  "size": "1024x1024",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "watch-marketing"
},
{
  "size": "16x16",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "16x16",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "32x32",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "32x32",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "128x128",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "128x128",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "256x256",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "256x256",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "512x512",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "mac"
},
{
  "size": "512x512",
  "scale": "2x",
  "idiom": "mac"
}
],
"info": {
   "version": 1,
   "author": "xcode"
}
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Really frustrating..

Comment: Set the Info.plist->device as iPhone/iPod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck with a similar error. The icons are there, no mistakes are in the info.plist or .csproj file. Visual Studio and XCode are completely up-to-date. I fixed it by building and running with an iPad deployment target. An iPad emulator is OK. After this, I made another archive, submitted it with Application Loader and everything was fine.

Comment: This problem suggests that you might have "Device-specific builds" enabled in your Project Options / iOS Build Options. Disable that and it should fix your issue as well.

Comment: comment of jstedfast actually solved my issue with missing icon files by not doint device-specific builds - thanks